# Android :: How do I remove focus from ALL Views in an activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, focus

I need a way to remove focus from ALL of the Views in an activity upon startup.


Is this possible?




I have already tried:

- Adding `android:focusable="true"` & `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the uppermost layout of my activity. Although this did ensure that no buttons or EditText fields were brought into focus, it presented another issue: the uppermost layout becomes focusable, which creates problems when using a keyboard to focus on views.

- Calling `getWindow().getCurrentFocus().clearFocus()` from the java file tied to my activity. I tried invoking this command from the `onResume()` and `onCreate()` functions. Unfortunately, `getWindow().getCurrentFocus()` always returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Remove focus of any button or text on the view. You should add it to your onCreate() method.

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```